# Insert INTO where clause on postgresql

Tags: postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert, on duplicate update (postgresql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

Is this possible on PostgreSQL:

```
insert record, if the record doesn't exists
else update existing record
```

Supposedly that the record will be inserted in this table structure:

```
[userid - unique] [count]
```

If there was an existing record, I will just update the count or insert if it doesn't exists

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a Function to do that in PostgreSQL, since there isn't something similar to mysql's [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) . Take a look at [this function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) at PostgreSQL official documentation.